# SQL Injection and possible attacks

Tags: java, sql, database, security, sql-injection

Hi I have the following query which is part of a java class. I just want to know what are the possible attacks possible with the SQL Injection. How an attacker can inject queries? What are sample queries in this case that can be used to gain access to the database?

```
    String query = ("SELECT username, password, admin FROM users 
    WHERE "  + "username='" + username + "' AND password='" + 
    password + "'"); 
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query); 
    // Entry in the result set means the query was successful and 
    //the user is a valid user
    if (rs.next()) { 
    username = rs.getString(1); 
    isAdmin = rs.getBoolean(3);
```

I think this is a possible way of attack also by putting username as abc';# since anything after # will be considered as a comment in SQL. What others think about it?

I want to know what the attacker will be entering in the username box and password box of the HTML page to gain access as an administrator. Assuming the job of the above java class is to process the request of the users's input from a HTML page by querying a database.

Comment: http://www.sqlinjectionwiki.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Just add this line above the first line, and run your code. It should give you an idea of what a malicious user can provide on user input : `String username = "me'; UPDATE users SET password='foo'; --"`

Comment: Depending on which RDBMS, you can do everything from dropping the database to totally compromising the machine.

Comment: nice reference on https://xkcd.com/327/ at the sqlinjectionwiki @DCoder :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically it works like this https://xkcd.com/327/

what I do is assuming, that everything a user inputs is a threat, so I would save everything to variables like `usUsername`, where "us" means unsafe.
After that I check every "us"-variable for injections, what results in `sUsername` (s means safe). So when I build a query I can only use s-varaibles and should be safe in most cases.

This idea is totally taken from here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: The best thing to do is to use parameterised queries, then you don't need to worry about sanitising the data specifically as it will never be "injectable".  Using string concatenation to build queries is never a good idea, even if you try and sanitise the values first.  It's too easy to let something bad through.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this code you could do ANYTHING you want by manipulating the values of the username or password text sent to the query.

The only constraint is the level of permission of the user account executing the query.  If it was a sysadmin, you could delete everything.  If it's SQL Server and xp_cmdshell is enabled, you could format the hard drive of the SQL server.

SQL Injection is one of those things where if you can do *something* you can pretty much do anything.

Look into the Havij tool, that is a security research tool that can demonstrate the power of SQLi.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. username and password can be replaced by anything leading to all types of queries. You must use a prepared statement to provide username and password

Answer (score 0):

Entering the following values for *password* would add a row to the result set containing the values `'admin'`, `'dummy'`, `1` for *username*, *password*, and *admin*, respectively:

```
' AND 1=0 UNION SELECT 'admin', 'dummy', admin FROM users WHERE admin = 1 AND '1'='1
```

The resulting query would look like:

```
SELECT username, password, admin FROM users 
WHERE username='dummy' AND password='' AND 1=0 UNION SELECT 'admin', 'dummy', admin FROM users WHERE admin = 1 AND '1'='1'
```

The first SELECT would return no result as `1=0` is false for each record. But the second, injected SELECT would return all records where `admin=1` is true and replaces the original values for *username* and *password* with `admin` and `dummy`, respectively.

You should [use prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and pass the values as parameters on execution.