# Active Android is it prone to SQL injections. Any known solution?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-injection, activeandroid

Android application is already developed using ActiveAndroid

```
public static List<ModelNames> search(String pattern) {
    return new Select().from(ModelNames.class)
            .where("title LIKE '%" + pattern + "%' or content LIKE '%" + pattern + "%'")
            .orderBy("title")
            .execute();
}
```

Now its prone to SQL injections.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and found a solution or could anyone provide a solution for the same?

Found a issue on [github](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/350#issuecomment-83663570), but could not get a proper solution.

Comment: You could clean and validate data before build the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [examples on the website](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Querying-the-database) show how to use placeholders:

```
public static List<ModelNames> search(String pattern) {
    pattern = "%" + pattern + "%";
    return new Select().from(ModelNames.class)
        .where("title LIKE ? or content LIKE ?", pattern, pattern)
        .orderBy("title")
        .execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is assuming, that everything a user inputs is a threat, so I would save everything to variables like usUsername, where "us" means unsafe. After that I check every "us"-variable for injections, what results in sUsername (s means safe). So when I build a query I can only use s-varaibles and should be safe in most cases.

This idea is totally taken from here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Already mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895941/sql-injection-and-possible-attacks/22896171#22896171).

Comment: This method *works*, but is still dangerous because without automatic checking, it's easy to overlook some query.

Comment: As I see it, it is totally hard to overlook something if everybody follows this simple convention. From what I believe it is indeed hard to catch everything in `sFromUs` and ideally should be delegated to the DB as prepared statement. I am (currently) not aware of that SQLite provides prepared statements, if so, this would be my answer.

Comment: SQLite has [prepared statements](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) and [parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). (This doesn't imply that the Android database API would make it easy to use them.)

Comment: So I have to rephrase to I am not aware of how to utilize SQLites prepared statements with the Android database API. Nonethless I will try to look into this on the next occasion.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a workaround, But I let other people to answer with better proposal with respect ActiveAndroid ORM.

following is the workaround:

```
public static List<ModelNames> search(String pattern) {
    return new Select().from(ModelNames.class)
             String pattern = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(searchBar.getText().toString());
             pattern = pattern.substring(1, pattern.length());
             pattern = pattern.substring(0, pattern.length()-1);
            .where("title LIKE '%" + pattern + "%' or content LIKE '%" + pattern + "%'")
            .orderBy("title")
            .execute();
}
```

Ref: [sqlEscapeString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString%28java.lang.String%29)